# Query assistance data from multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables in access 2016 they are

```
EmployeeInformation(ID (PK), FirstName, LastName, Employee) 
Trainings(TrainingID (PK), TrainingName)
CompletedTrainings(RecordID (PK), Employee, Training, Completed, Expired)
```

1st table Employee is a calculated field that is their first name and last name combined. 3rd table Employee and training are lookup fields from the other 2 tables and completed and expired are dates.

I want to create a query that will 
-display all employees 
-display all trainings
-display all completed and expired dates
-if there is an employee that did not complete a training that employee will be listed along with the training and the completed and expired date will be null.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is a text field that stores a combination of the first and last name

Comment: The only option to join is EmployeeInformation.ID to CompletedTrainings.Employee

Comment: You need a dataset of all possible combinations of employee and training. This dataset can be created with a cartesian relationship query - every record of each table will associate with every record of other table: `SELECT EmployeeInformation.ID, Trainings.ID FROM EmployeeInformation, Trainings;`. Now join that query to the CompletedTrainings - compound join on both ID fields. I agree, names make very poor unique identifier. Save ID as foreign key.

Comment: Thank you for your input I am self teaching myself and you guys are helping immensely. I have created the relationship query. Do I create a second query to compound join both ID fields. And when i create the join is it employeeinfo.ID to CompletedTrainings ID?